# Why does NetLogo create a Blob instead of a clear shape?

Tags: netlogo

I am a beginner in coding. I am happy to get constructive critique not only about my problems but also about the way I describe them.

I have a problem with this code in NetLogo:

```
patches-own[grass]
to setup
  clear-all
  ask one-of patches              ;;pic a random patch as center of the pasture
    [set grass 1]                 ;;and plant grass on it
  ask patches                     ;;search through all the patches to find the one (or several ones) 
    [if grass > 0                 ;;with grass on it
      [ask patches in-radius 3    ;;select the area arround the patch with the grass
        [set grass 1]]]             ;;and also plant grass here
   ask patches                     ;;search through all the patches to find the one (or several ones)
    [if grass > 0                 ;;with grass on it
      [set pcolor green]]         ;;and paint them green
  reset-ticks
  end
```

The original code was bigger, but I narrowed the problem down to this snippet. It is part of the set-up process of the model-world and the aim here is to create a pasture of a defined size randomly on the model-world. (For cows to search and eat, but that’s not the subject now)

I expected the code to randomly pic a patch and plant grass on it and then increase the vegetated area around this patch to a certain size. So what I expected as an outcome was something like this:

[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlUD9.png)

But instead I get a green area of variable sizes and shapes that sometimes covers the whole world. Just like the Blob. Here some examples of its different appearance:

[the blobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwULd.png)

The “Blob-creation” could be bypassed, for example if the first patch with grass is painted green right after it is defined and then in the second step search for the green patch instead of the patch with grass > 0. Anyway every solution I found demands additional steps which I hope to avoid. And most important is, that I want to understand why this happens, so I could avoid it or even use it in the future.

The code is very simple and clear. So I guess it’s more a problem of understanding Netlogos interpretation of the commands.

Why is NeLogo not executing the commands as I expect it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! The key part is this bit:

```
  ask patches                     ;;search through all the patches to find the one (or several ones) 
    [if grass > 0                 ;;with grass on it
      [ask patches in-radius 3    ;;select the area arround the patch with the grass
        [set grass 1]]]
```

`ask` iterates through each of the patches, having each run the enclosed code in turn. `ask` does so in random order (or, more accurately, agentsets, such as `patches`, are unordered). As an example, suppose patch 0 0 runs this code and gives the surrounding patches grass. Patch 0 1 happens to run next. Since it now has grass (given to it by patch 0 0), it also gives grass to its neighbors. Now, suppose path 0 2 happens to run next, and so forth. Thus, the shape of the blob is going to depend on the order the patches run the code in. If a patch has been given grass by one of its neighbors, it will give its neighbors grass.

Luckily, the fix is simple. Rather than checking if a patch has grass when it runs that code block, you can ask just patches with grass to run it using `with`. This looks like this:

```
  ask patches with [ grass > 0 ] ;;search through all the patches to find the one (or several ones) 
    [ask patches in-radius 3     ;;select the area arround the patch with the grass
      [set grass 1]]
```

`patches with [ grass > 0 ]` refers to just those patches with grass (before any patches do anything), so that patches that get grass while the ask is running won't end up running it themselves.

Comment: Hallo Bryan, that is great, Thank you very much. I love that solution, ´cause it is so simple and does not blow up the whole ccode. I tried it and it works perfectly now. Thank You very much. best regards Hannes

Comment: Happy to help! Make sure to mark the answer correct if you're satisfied with it so that others know this question is answered.

Comment: Hallo Bryan, thanks for the advice, I was not aware of that. I changed the titel and klicked the green chekmark. Is that suficcend?

Comment: Thanks Hannes! That's great. In the future, just the green check is sufficient :)